# Prove that exist $c \in (a;b)$ such that $1975 f(a)+297 f(b)=2004 f(c)$

Tags: functions, polynomials, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial, $a<b$ such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$. Prove that exists $c\in (a;b)$ such that $1975 f(a)+297 f(b)=2004 f(c)$. Please help me! Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false. For example, take $f(x)=x^2$, and take $a=-1, b=\sqrt{\frac{30}{297}}$. (*Note here that $b<1$, it will be important later*)

Then, $1975 f(a)+297 f(b)=2004f(c)$ translates to $$c^2=\frac{1975 \cdot 1 + 297\cdot\frac{30}{297}}{2004} = \frac{1975 + 30}{2004} = \frac{2005}{2004} > 1.$$

This means that $|c|>1$, but $c\in (a,b)\subseteq (-1,1)$ implies $|c|<1$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there might be a typo in your question. We can prove that there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that
$$1975 f(a) + \color{red}{29} f(b) = 2004 f(c)$$
Indeed, consider the function
$$g(x) = 1975f(a) + 29f(b) - 2004 f(x)$$
Suppose that $f(a) < f(b)$. Then:
$$\begin{align*}
g(a) & = 1975 f(a) + 29 f(b) - 2004 f(a) = 29 (f(b) - f(a)) > 0 \\
g(b) & = 1975 f(a) + 29 f(b) - 2004 f(b) = 1975 (f(a) - f(b)) < 0
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $g(c) = 0$, that is:
$$1975 f(a) + 29 f(b) = 2004 f(c)$$
If $f(a) > f(b)$, the result still holds by the same reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @5xum, this is not true as it's written. Either you need further assumptions on $f$, or you want to prove a different result.

The reason I say this is that this kind of problem is usually tackled through the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). Since polynomials are continuous functions, given $a<b$ such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$ (without loss of generality, $f(a)<f(b)$), it's true that for every value $\xi$ such that $f(a)<\xi<f(b)$, there exists $c$ such that $a<c<b$ and $f(c)=\xi$.

In particular, given $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha+\beta=1$, the value $\alpha f(a) + \beta f(b)$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ (this is a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination)), so the theorem applies, and there is $c$ satisfying the assumptions such that $f(c) = \alpha f(a) + \beta f(b)$. Your problem is not of this form, unfortunately, but one cannot help noticing that $1975 f(a) + 29 f(b) = 2004 f(c)$ is. A typo, perhaps?